# Indexing a Value Back Into A List - Why is it saying that it is not in the list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to use the list.index() function but it is saying that the object I am trying to index is not in the list.

I've not tried much because to be honest I don't really know, much about python but I have tried searching the question online.

```
heartsCards = ["Ace of Hearts","Two of Hearts","Three of Hearts","Four of Hearts","Five of Hearts","Six of Hearts","Seven of Hearts","Eight of Hearts","Nine of Hearts","Ten of Hearts","Jack of Hearts","Queen of Hearts","King of Hearts"]
diamondsCards = ["Ace of Diamonds","Two of Diamonds","Three of Diamonds","Four of Diamonds","Five of Diamonds","Six of Diamonds","Seven of Diamonds","Eight of Diamonds","Nine of Diamonds","Ten of Diamonds","Jack of Diamonds","Queen of Diamonds","King of Diamonds"]
clubsCards = ["Ace of Clubs","Two of Clubs","Three of Clubs","Four of Clubs","Five of Clubs","Six of Clubs","Seven of Clubs","Eight of Clubs","Nine of Clubs","Ten of Clubs","Jack of Clubs","Queen of Clubs","King of Clubs"]
spadesCards = ["Ace of Spades","Two of Spades","Three of Spades","Four of Spades","Five of Spades","Six of Spades","Seven of Spades","Eight of Spades","Nine of Spades","Ten of Spades","Jack of Spades","Queen of Spades","King of Spades"]

yourCards = []

cardValue = 0

def pickUp():
    randomNum = random.randint(1,4)

    if randomNum == 1:
        temp = random.choice(heartsCards)
        yourCards.append(temp)
        heartsCards.remove(temp)

    if randomNum == 2:
        temp = random.choice(diamondsCards)
        yourCards.append(temp)
        diamondsCards.remove(temp)

    if randomNum == 3:
        temp = random.choice(clubsCards)
        yourCards.append(temp)
        clubsCards.remove(temp)

    if randomNum == 4:
        temp = random.choice(spadesCards)
        yourCards.append(temp)
        spadesCards.remove(temp)

def cardCount():
    global cardValue

    for card in yourCards:
        if card.count("Hearts") != 0:
            cardValue =+ heartsCards.index(card) + 1

        if card.count("Diamonds") != 0:
            cardValue =+ diamondsCards.index(card) + 1

        if card.count("Clubs") != 0:
            cardValue =+ clubsCards.index(card) + 1

        if card.count("Spades") != 0:
            cardValue =+ spadesCards.index(card) + 1
    return cardValue 

pickUp()
pickUp()

cardCount()
```

I expected the variable cardValue to be printed as the value of the cards. However I recieved this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\Pontoon.py", line 97, in <module>
    cardCount()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\Pontoon.py", line 68, in cardCount
    cardValue =+ diamondsCards.index(card) + 1
ValueError: 'Nine of Diamonds' is not in list
```

Comment: When `pickUp()` chooses a card, it is removed from the suit list.  You can no longer use `.index()` to find its position in that list.

Comment: of course lol Ill close it now

Answer (score -1):

what [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) said in a comment, works:

> When `pickUp()` chooses a card, it is removed from the suit list. You can no longer use `.index()` to find its position in that list.